# Why is my Ajax controller not correctly rendering a partial despite logs returning 200 response?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a js file with the following code:

```
class App.SimilarProjects

constructor: ->
    return unless $('#projects_show_page').length
    $('#similar_projects').html('')
    $('#related_spinner').removeClass('hidden')
    projectId = $('#similar_projects').data('projectId')
    $.ajax
      url: "/p/#{ projectId }/similar_by_tags.js"
      success: (data) ->
        $('#similar_projects').html(data)
      complete: ->
        $('#related_spinner').addClass('hidden')
```

This is pretty straightforward code. in my controller action called `projects_controller.rb` I have this code to handle the request:

```
def similar_by_tags
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js { render partial: 'projects/show/similar_by_tags', locals: { similar_by_tags: @project.related_by_tags(4) } }
  end
end
```

Currently, this implementation is not successfully rendering the partial. However, here is a snapshot of the logs.

```
Started GET "/p/firefox/similar_by_tags.js" for ::1 at 2017-06-20 13:55:36 -0400
Processing by ProjectsController#similar_by_tags as JS

*************

Rendered projects/show/_similar_by_tags.html.haml (398.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 461ms (Views: 63.0ms | ActiveRecord: 348.4ms)
```

Why is this partial not rendering itself? I have looked at stack overflow questions with similar problems, tried the recommendations found here and still to no avail. What can I be doing wrong here? The data variable on the success doesn't `console.log` when I try to see what it is. It's very confusing.

[Ajax 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16884636/rails-render-partial-after-ajax-get-request)
[Ajax 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13319454/how-to-render-a-partial-from-controller-after-making-an-ajax-call)
[Ajax 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9527925/rails-rendering-partials-through-ajax?rq=1)

Comment: Logs say that the partial is being rendered. How are you determining that it is not being rendered?

Comment: @Vimsha thanks for the reply. I am looking at the page where the html should be rendering and its not rendering. There's no html to be seen and the `data` variable is blank.